# SASS dynamic string variables

Tags: css, sass

Is there any way with Sass or Less to use a dynamic variable that can change based on conditions? Something like this, with `$year` being the dynamic variable. I know I can do this with javascript, but I thought a CSS precompiler might have this functionality as well.

```
$year: '2021'; //can change based on some logic

.one {
      grid-area: one;
      background-image: url(/images/items/$year/1.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to reassign the value of `$year` if a certain condition? Or just straightup dynamically compute `$year`'s value based on conditions using a mixin or function?

Comment: Reassign if a condition

Answer (score 1):

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation is what you want.

The docs give you an example of what you're trying to do

Combine it with SCSS control statements like [`@if`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if).

So for your example:

```
$year: '2021'; //can change based on some logic

.one {
      grid-area: one;
      background-image: url(/images/items/#{$year}/1.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reassign the value of `$year` based on a condition using [`@if`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/if) and use [interpolation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation) with `#{$var}` syntax to populate the value for `$year` in the background-image declaration.

```
$year: '2021';
$month: 'January';
$color: green;

@if $month == 'January' {
  $year: '2022';
  $color: #f06;
}

/* Use updated variables */
.one {
 color: $color;
 grid-area: one;
 background-image: url(/images/items/#{$year}/1.jpg);
}
```